# Illegal path address in JBoss CLI (WFLYCTL0387)

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-cli

I try to use the JBoss CLI (on RedHat JBoss EAP 7.4-5) to add a cluster connection in the messaging subsystem via the following CLI command:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/cluster-connection=jmscluster:add(address=jms, connector-name=http-connector, discovery-group=dg-group1)
```

I get the following answer:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] {
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0387: Illegal path address 'jms' , it is not in a correct CLI format"
}
```

All I found about the address in the [JBoss documentation - 29.2 Server-side Message Load Balancing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/configuring_messaging/clusters_overview):

"*In the case shown above the cluster connection will load balance messages sent to addresses that start with "jms". This cluster connection will, in effect, apply to all Jakarta Messaging queues and topics since they map to core queues that start with the substring "jms".*"

Does anybody can tell me what the *correct CLI format* for the path address would look like?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for the hint, I just edited the question. It's JBoss 7.4-5

Comment: Yes, it's a RedHat JBoss EAP, but I guess the behaviour would be similar on a current WildFly server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `cluster-connection-address` instead of `address`, e.g.:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/cluster-connection=jmscluster:add(cluster-connection-address=jms, connector-name=http-connector, discovery-group=dg-group1)
```

If you just type this much:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/cluster-connection=jmscluster:add(
```

And the press the "Tab" key you'll see a list of all the supported attributes, e.g.:

```
!                              confirmation-window-size       max-retry-interval             reconnect-attempts
allow-direct-connections-only  connection-ttl                 message-load-balancing-type    retry-intervald(
call-failover-timeout          connector-name*                min-large-message-size         retry-interval-multiplier
call-timeout                   discovery-group*               notification-attempts          static-connectors*
check-period                   initial-connect-attempts       notification-interval          use-duplicate-detection
cluster-connection-address*    max-hops                       producer-window-size
```

Comment: `/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/cluster-connection=jmscluster:read-operation-description(name=add)` would have helped me as well if I would have read it carefully :|